# Parsing JSON remote call and store it locally

Tags: android, database, json, parsing

I need to parse a remote response from a URL that retrieves a big JSON object and store it locally so we can perform searches for example, in an activity in Android.
I've been trying to look it up but I can't find any approach about how to do it.

Any suggestion/help please?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Gson parsing to parse the JSON from url.

For Storing the result use sqlite Database.

Here is the good example for [GSON parsing](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html)

For sqlite follow this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

Answer (score 1):

the retrieved JSON response is stored in the BufferReader i.e.,

```
urlClientStream = openHttpClientPostConnection(searchURL,
                        urlParams.toString());

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(urlClientStream), 8192);

                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line);
                }

                JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObject(buffer.toString())
                        .getJSONObject("RESPONSE");
```

Hope this helps you